# Match ID and column names and update the data

Tags: r

I have two data files, one is the master file and another one is a smaller file. I need to update the master file with the data in the small file by matching the unique ID number and the specific columns.

For example:

```
Master file (X)
ID a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
1  a  d  4  5  6  8
2  d  f  NA 1  3  12
3  e  r  1  1  89 0
4  f  we 10 NA 3  9
5  dd w  NA 21 56 7

Small file (iy1)
ID  b1 b2 
1   4  5
2   27 1
3   1  1
4   10 9
5   56 21
```

I have tried

```
X$b1[na.omit(match(iy1$ID, X$ID))] <- iy1$b1[which(iy1$ID %in% X$ID)]
```

but this is tedious if I have 1000 records and 1000 columns to be updated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
# Master file (X)
X = read.table(text = 
"ID a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
1  a  d  4  5  6  8
2  d  f  NA 1  3  12
3  e  r  1  1  89 0
4  f  we 10 NA 3  9
42  f  we 10 NA 3  9
5  dd w  NA 21 56 7",
header = TRUE)
# Small file (iy1)
iy1 = read.table(text = 
"ID  b1 b2 
5   4  5
4   27 1
3   1  1
2   10 9
21   10 9
1   56 21",
header = TRUE)

### Solution
# we suppose that ID's are unique in both datasets
to_update = c("b1", "b2") # columns which we want to update
updatable_id = intersect(X$ID, iy1$ID) # ID's which we can update
X[match(updatable_id, X$ID), to_update] = iy1[match(updatable_id, iy1$ID), to_update] # update
```

Comment: You should change the `stringsAsFactors` option back to TRUE at the end if you're doing it that way.  Changing that option is dangerous.  `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` isn't that much to type into each `read.table()` call.

Comment: @RichardScriven I've removed `stringsAsFactors`. Actually it is not needed here at all. In general I don't think it is dangerous. Contrary, all becomes better for me with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE `.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setdiff(intersect(names(iy1), names(X)), "ID")
setDT(X)[iy1, (nm1) := mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), on = "ID"]
X
#    ID a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
#1:  1  a  d  4  5  6  8
#2:  2  d  f 27  1  3 12
#3:  3  e  r  1  1 89  0
#4:  4  f we 10  9  3  9
#5:  5 dd  w 56 21 56  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using base R

```
sapply(colnames(iy1),function(t) x[which(is.na(x[t])),t]<<-iy1[which(is.na(x[t])),t])
```